# metro-style apps update behavior

Tags: windows-8, settings, microsoft-metro, updates

Which ways users can update Windows 8 metro-style apps installed on machine, considering a existing new version on Store?

Apps that uses `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` to save some user data, when the app is updated, this settings are removed/reset or saved between versions?

And what is the behavior of `LocalSettings` when user uninstalls and reinstalls the app manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings are persisted between versions.
The LocalSettings are removed when the user uninstalls the app.